# authentication facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I have developed a facebook application, where users upload video and audio. Now i want that without authentication no user will be able to use the application.

Why i want this is because i need the user profile picture, the `current loggedin user profile picture`. So that i can welcome him after authentication.

After searching for hours, i was unable to get answer for myself, so posting it here.

I have read the complete documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/

but unable to understand. It would be great if anyone can help me.

Comment: what type of app is this? A canvas app, a pagetab app as your link suggests or a website? Do you have a code example? The docs generally cover this in great detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for authentification for canvas application then read [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas/).

If you wanna use server-side authentification then download official php SDK from [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src). Repository contains [example application](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php).
I've recommend this way of authentification because it is the easiest. [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) for SDK.

And exists client-side way of autentification. Documentation for [JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and [example application](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/).